# How to recognize which model of fax modem I have

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, modem

I have an old fax modem that I should install it's driver on Windows xp. How can I find it's model for installing it's driver?

When I removed it from PCI slot I only found GIGABYTE brand on the main board and it seems there is no model on it.

How can I recognize it's model and where can I find that driver?  I Googled it hundred of times but I couldn't find any gigabyte fax modem driver for download!

Comment: did i ask this question in the right place -> i know this is a stupid question, but that system is not mine and i should fix it!

Comment: Get in a time machine and go back to 1996. Flag down someone who knows what a fax modem is. Alternatively, Google the PCI device ID.

Comment: where is that id, there are some numbers on it that i do n't know what are they! would you please lead me to find that ID!

Comment: http://techpp.com/2010/01/12/identify-and-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices-in-windows/

Comment: If the method linked to by ta.speot.is doesn't work in this case, you could look up the part number of the (probably) biggest IC on the board, if it is visible. Then you would be able to find a generic driver for it. ([How to identify computer chips or integrated circuits on circuit boards](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_identify_computer_chips_or_integrated_circuits_on_circuit_boards).)